GPU without using PCIE or CPU integrated graphics on NAS self build?
I'm building a NAS. I want to use micro ITX which have a single PICE slot. I want to use ECC memory and AMD CPU. From Asrock product pages it looks like most of their current AMD AM5 line support DDR5 ECC. They have a lot of asterisks in their documentation and I'm still wading through it to figure out what memory is actually supported. A mobo won't post without a GPU or APU of some kind (don't think they have headless mobo options).
I have 2 options and I don't like either:

Use an AMD APU (those with G in the name). These are more expensive, slower, and I think I need to use pro series to get ECC support (at least this was the case for AM4 motherboards). Seems like a waste of money to pay for a APU and get slower processor that is capable of running games when I just need an ASCII terminal.

Use the PCIE slot to insert a graphics card. I don't want to waste the 1 PCIE slot available on ITX form factor. I've seen issues in forums with TrueNAS NIC card compatibility and there is no HCL so I need to reserve this for a NIC card if the on board one doesn't work (also wanting 10gbe network card long term and PCIE is probably the only option)


I'm not planning on transcoding or media server. I am planning on full SATA SSD hard drives for my NAS (for noise mainly rather than speed but if I get 10gbe NIC then throughput should hopefully keep up with 6gbps SATA). I will do no gaming obviously. I don't want to compromise on the overall system (waste pcie slot or use more expensive/slower processor) just to get a GPU so I can see the ASCII terminal to install the OS etc. I may use some VMs on the box but for now the plan is just data storage.
Ive read you can use M.2 NVME slot to insert some sort of graphics. Im thinking of 3d printing the case so I can find a way to insert an extra video port on the back of the case if needed.
So my question is this: Assuming I have 2 NVME slots, I don't want to use the PCIE slot, and I don't want to use AMD APU / pro cpu. Is there some way to get a motherboard to post without either of these options? I'm open to all crazy sounding options.

Do modern firmwares really have no option to boot without a GPU? (Much like they have options to boot without a keyboard, etc.)

yes they really do from what I read. They expect integrated graphics or a proper video card. Many forum posts "my mobo wont post" and all because they dont have GPU.

I found something like this but cant find it for sale anywhere. https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=M2_VGA#Specifications

also considering a pcie riser card for the M.2 slot and a 20$ graphics card which I will .... idk ... crazy glue onto the mother board ;) jk - Ill probably design my own case and 3d print it.

Thanks for the comments! Im admittedly lacking in understanding how PCIE lanes work and bifurcation. I was trying to research it but couldnt find a good article (for instance if I plug in a pcie graphics card will it take PCIE lanes and hurt other peripherals). Im not sure of anything but the only way to know is to get the board and have it not start. The asrok page literally does say "Some CPUs do not have integrated graphics. A PCIe graphics card must be added for output" here:  https://pg.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B650E%20PG-ITX%20WiFi/index.us.asp#CPU .

Ive also seen may people post similar things about motherboards not posting with CPUs that dont have integrated graphics. The mobo has hdmi / display port plugs but I still think they need either a PCIE graphics card or integrated graphics on the CPU. Searching google for "can mobo post without pcie or integrated graphics" returns: "Yes, a motherboard can post without a PCIe or integrated graphics card if the CPU has integrated graphics". Im talking about a CPU without integrated graphics. AMD cpus with graphics are known as APUs and any cpu with a G is an APU (5700G). 8400F ryzen is not.

Im thinking to get a riser PCIE cable that can connect to the mobo M.2 and plug in a cheap GPU. Then I also read someone did that and his computer caught on fire (not joking) so thinking twice about it.

The edits others made removed a line you'd repeated that did not add anything to the question. It was done by a high-rep user who already has all the badges. Acting rudely towards people you're hoping to receive help from is often not a good way to get good help. I've done more cleanup on your question to make it clearer. Note that the line you insisted on adding back makes your question broad and therefore off-topic. Do not add it back. You have an OK-ish and mostly answerable question here, adding that line back will only attract more close votes.

Since AM5 AMD has opted to include integrated graphics (iGPU) on their CPU's. They now ,like intel, add an F suffix to the CPU name (eg Ryzen 5 7500F) to indicate the lack of iGPU. These are not APU's and do not suffer from possible lower CPU performance.
Just get any normal AM5 CPU and you're good to go.

ah that makes sense - was wondering why some have an F and some have no letter. I did read that F means no integrated graphics and saw some posts that no letter meant the same. Ill go with the no letter option. Thanks!

You're mistaken about the "no graphics unless G". The G-suffixed models have a far more powerful integrated GPU; this can easily be 500% faster. But e.g. the Ryzen 5 7600 "non-G" still has basic graphics. Enough to boot and install an OS. Only the F-suffixed models require an external graphics card.
This is new since the Ryzen 7000 series (AM5 socket); for the 5000 series and earlier (AM4) you're indeed out of luck. See https://www.amd.com/en/products/processors/desktops/ryzen.html#specifications

thanks! upvoted but silbee had the same answer a bit earlier. I appreciate the response!
